# How to find common items of a listview1 and shared preferences listview

Tags: android, firebase, listview

I have three listviews.

1. Listview1 ( firebase list view)
2. Listview2 ( storing deleted chats)

I deleted some items of  Listview1 locally for me.

And stored them in  Listview2.

`Map = Listview1.get((int)_position); Listview2.add(Map);  Listview1.removeAll(Listview2);  ((BaseAdapter)ListView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged(); Map.clear();`

Now
Those items deleted.

Then if I add a new child to firebase, the deleted listitems still remains in the Listview1.

So i used
`Listview1.removeAll(Listview2);`
Again.

But this time nothing is removed. I don't know why?
Please help me...

Comment: what you want exactly to do?

Comment: ```adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();```  did you added this line

Comment: Yes It is there.

Comment: ```yourlist.setListAdapter(null);``` use this method

Comment: I want if I add new child also the deleted items removed.

Comment: No, the list is not null. I checked using toast to get size of Listview2.

Comment: you want to delete only listview1 right?

Comment: Yes , actually i want that deleted messages will not be shown again in Listview1. But it should be there in firebase for other users.